# How do I get a sticky footer?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I know there have been plenty of questions regarding sticky footers, but I can't seem to get them to work on my page.

Can anyone help me make my footer sticky, not fixed?

My HTML

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#container {
    width: 980px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }

#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;  }

#footer {
    width: 3000px;
    min-height: 185px;
    background-color: rgb(0,173,239);
    margin-left: -1000px;  }
```

I have tried various positions (relative, fixed etc) but it doesn't work. I seem to get my footer fixed and covering content. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have a look at [cssstickyfooter.com](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)? Also: tell us which browsers you want/need to support.

Comment: Yea I have, and I couldn't get it to work. I am wanting support on all browsers (chrome, FF, safari, IE 8 and 9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 100%; }

#container {
    width: 980px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }

#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
    margin-bottom: 290px;  }

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 185px;
    background-color: rgb(0,173,239);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;  }
```

Comment: This covers content on longer pages, which is why I wanted a sticky footer rather than fixed

Comment: Could you send a screenshot? What browser do you use?

Comment: I am wanting all browsers. I want the footer to sit at the bottom of the content, but if the page is short, then make the footer sit on the bottom of the page

Comment: Okay I've got two ideas: Add min-height:100%; to body or try http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ as it should work...

Comment: I added min-height 100% to body and html. Bingo! Thanks